# Image on published shiny app won't appear on the app

Tags: r, image, shiny, shiny-server

I published this app before and it displayed the image and worked fine, but the last time I republished it the image did not appear anymore.

I have a folder with ui.R, server.R and the www folder where I have the image I want to display on my app. The code works fine when I reload the app, I can see the image and the app does everything it is supposed to do. However, when I do runApp() and publish the app, the image wont show.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you use any absolute paths in your app? These may work locally, but they certainly wouldn't work when the app is published on a remote server.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like you should always republish using the same folder where the app was initially published. That's what I did and the problem was solved.